# Unique representations of Python objects

Tags: python, object, caching, constructor, decorator

Let C be a Python class and assume that the constructor of C takes an integer as argument.

Consider now the instructions

```
x = C(0)
y = C(0)
```

The default behavior of Python implies that x and y occupy two different place in the memory.

> Is it possible to force x and y to share the same place in memory?

I would be very happy if some Python decorator makes the job.

**[Note]** I am looking for a way to memoize constructors (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization for the memoization of functions).

**[Add]** The Sage Open Source Mathematics Software provides a very good solution to this problem through the class `UniqueRepresentation` (see [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/structure/sage/structure/unique_representation.html)). Any class should inherit from this one to have the expected behavior. Nevertheless, I am wondering if there is a pure Python solution to this problem.

Comment: Uhh... why not `x = y = C(0)`? or `x = C(0); y=x`?

Comment: But why x = y = C(0)? I want, when two objects are mathematically equivalent, that they share the same memory place. Assume that x = C(0) is defined as a local variable of a function f and y = C(0) is defined as a local variable of another function g.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like copy-on-demand; like what happens when you `fork()`? Also, testing for equality in the sense of `x==y` is what `__eq__` is for

Comment: I am searching a way to do memoization of constructors.

Comment: Please explain `memoization of constructors`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization explains memoization of functions. In Python, you can make this in a generic way with the help of a decorator. I am searching a way to do the same thing with constructors instead of functions.

Comment: When python creates a new instance of an object it takes a different location in memory.  The only way to get two objects to share the same memory address is to create one then make the other a copy of the first.

Comment: This is desired behavior.  Consider `a = []; b = []`.  If these were the same object, every time you `.append`ed to a list in python all other lists would get appended to as well.

Comment: I know what memoization is. I was asking how you wanted to apply it to constructors

Comment: @inspectorG4dget This is exactly the point of my question.

Comment: @SethMMorton This is not true in a functional programming fashion and this is not MY desired behavior. Mathematically, it is reasonable to ask that two equal objects are at a same place in memory.

Comment: Will the two objects ever be different?  If so, they will need to then occupy different locations in memory.  I suppose I'm asking if these objects mutable or non-mutable.

Comment: In a first approximation, we only consider the case where objects are non-mutable.

Comment: Do you object to a function that returns an instance of the class?  I think that it is a limitation in python that each time you call a class's `__init__` it creates a new object in memory.  However, I can imagine getting around this by creating a function that will return a class instance.

Comment: To comment on my previous comment, I'm not so sure this would be considered a "limitation" by the author of python... he might consider it a "feature".  In general, if you are concerned about the memory address of your objects, you might need to be using something a bit more heavyweight like `C++`.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about why you are saying it is reasonable to expect this based on mathematics.  Computer programming and mathematics don't always agree.  Try `0.9-0.8==0.1`.

Comment: @SethMMorton I program mainly to make computer experimentations and explorations in the field of combinatorics. Then, I handle among others trees and words, and these are programmed as non-mutable objects for the sake of simplicity and soundness. Thus, I do not see good reasons to allow two mathematically equal objects to be physically different. I see only good reason for the converse (including simplicity, soundness, and also efficiency).

Comment: OK.  Based on your edit regarding Sage's `UniqueRepresentation`, it seems that what you are talking about is more in the realm of Mathematics or possibly theoretical computer science.  Python was not created with this in mind (it's a scripting language by design), so this is probably why the feature you desire is not builtin to the language.  This is probably why the python community on SO gave you a hard time... it's not a concept that python developers think about.

Comment: Indeed. Thank for your time anyway :-) !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).  If your class definition is

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
```

then it behaves like

```
>>> a = C(1)
>>> a.num = 2
>>> b = C(1)
>>> b.num
2
>>> a is b
True
```

However, this makes the name `C` a function, and any class features aren't usable before the class is actually instantiated.  If you want, you can also directly cache the method `__new__`, which is responsible for the creation of the object.  `__new__` is a method which takes all the same arguments as `__init__` and it is called before `__init__` when we create class instances.

As caching the output of `__new__` is straightforward, we could make things a little bit more interesting.  Let's create a new decorator, which works just like `lru_cache`, but it can be used with classes to cache the output of `__new__`:

```
def lru_cache_class(maxsize):
    def wrap(klass):
        @lru_cache(maxsize=maxsize)
        def new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            self = object.__new__(cls)
            return self
        klass.__new__ = new
        return klass
    return wrap
```

We give `__new__` all possible arguments and keyword arguments so that it can be used with other classes as well.  Now we can cache the instances of class `C2` like this:

```
@lru_cache_class(maxsize=32)
class C2(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
```

And we can see that the objects are cached:

```
>>> c = C2(2)
>>> c is C2(2)
True
```

There is, however, another subtle difference in this approach compared to the first.  For instance:

```
>>> d = C2(3)
>>> d.num = 4
>>> d.num
4
>>> e = C2(3)
>>> d.num == e.num
>>> d.num
3
```

This behavior is expected because `__init__` is called anyway, although the object's memory location remains the same.  Depending on your use case, you may want to cache the output of `__init__` as well.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but the problem is that the decorator `@lru_cache` turn the symbol `C` into a function identifier. Is there a similar solution that preserves the fact that `C` is a class?

Comment: You're right.  I just edited my answer to show another way, which keeps the name `C` as a class.

Comment: Thanks, this seems very great! Nevertheless, it would be very useful to have a class decorator to obtain the same behavior.

Comment: Your solution is very interesting, but I think that there are some few issues. Your class decorator creates a new class from the input one. This new class loses some properties of the first one, like its doctstring. I think that an excellent solution does not create and return a new class but just add a memoized version of `__new__` to the input class. Do you think that this is feasible ?

Comment: Overriding methods (`__new__` in this case) is only possible by inheritance.  Your concern about the class docstring is easily fixed -- just define `__doc__` attribute to be that of the parent class.  If you also want some nice string representation that points to the base class, you need to specify `__str__` method in the definition. But the excellent solution that you are expecting is just defining `__new__` with the `lru_cache` decorator in you class definition `C` (this is what I suggested before the last edit).

Comment: I think you are right. Nevertheless, I would like that the new class preserves exactly the same behavior as the former one. The lack of the docstring seems to be one of several lacks. Indeed, as you say, it is possible to fix this problem quit easily. Are there some attributes which need affectations (from former class to the new one)?

Comment: At least `__doc__` and `__name__` attributes will be automatically overridden in the sub-class.  The first one you can set to `BaseClass.__doc__`, but the other you cannot easily change.  With other names that are not defines, the interpreter will find the names from the parent class.  [CPython reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html) explains these.  It is also possible to create classes using [type](http://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/type-name-bases-dict.html), but this can get much more complicated.

Comment: Okay, it appears I was wrong.  Is the behavior now what you would expect?

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior I expect. For the last part of your answer, a problem can occur if objects of the memoized class can be muted. The unique representation pattern is sound only if applied on classes with immutable objects (which seems to be somewhat complicated to write class decorators preventing calls of `__setattr__`). Thanks for your response!

Comment: Yes, this only checks the input to the constructor and doesn't care whether the object is immutable or not.  Also, if the input to the constructor is not a hashable object (a list for instance), the cache will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You could just override the `__new__` to store cached versions of each object:

```
class C(object):
    _cache = {}

    def __new__(cls, x):
        if x not in C._cache:
            C._cache[x] = object.__new__(cls, x)
        return C._cache[x]

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> a = C(1)
>>> b = C(1)
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```

Obviously, if you later change `x` instead of creating a new class, it won't become the same object as one previously defined with that value of `x`:

```
>>> a = C(1)
>>> b = C(2)
>>> a.x = 2
>>> a is b
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to have a function create the class instance for you, this might work.  Assuming you have your class `C` that accepts an integer:

```
def C_getter(num, _class_archive={}):
    """\
    Returns an instance of the `C` class,
    making sure that if an object already exists with that
    integer number a new object is not created.

    The _class_archive is used to keep a record of all the instances
    in memory local to this function.  Don't actually supply an
    argument to _class_archive when you call this function.
    """

    if num not in _class_archive:
        _class_archive[num] = C(num)
    return _class_archive[num]
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> a = C_getter(0)
>>> b = C_getter(0)
>>> a is b
True
>>> c = C(0)
>>> a is c
False
```

I am taking advantage of the fact that if you use a mutable object as a default argument to a function, the *same* mutable object is used for each time the function is called.

**Edit**

If you wanted to make this generic (assuming all your classes need a single number), you could do the following:

```
def getter(your_class, num, _class_archive={}):
    if (your_class, num) not in _class_archive:
        _class_archive[(your_class, num)] = your_class(num)
    return _class_archive[(your_class, num)]
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> a = getter(C, 0)
>>> b = getter(C, 0)
>>> c = getter(A, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this solution is not generic in the following sense: you have to define, for each class A, a function A_getter. Moreover, I think that it is more accurate to define this function as a static method or a class method of C. This also works well but I think that it is a pity to (1) have to construct objects not through the constructor, (2) have to define a same static (or class) method for any class.

Comment: @SamueleGiraudo I have made it a bit more generic, but it still won't satisfy all your criteria.

Comment: This is a nice solution even if it indeed not satisfies all my criteria (I cannot up-vote because I have not enough reputation, sorry). Maybe, it is possible to improve it a little by replacing the argument `num` by `*args` to cover the case where constructors need any parameters.

Comment: @SamueleGiraudo I thought of that, but in python 2.x this would require `_class_archive` to be *before* `*args`, and then you would have to supply an argument for `_class_archive` when you call the function, completely defeating the purpose.